# Generic View shared between 2 or more ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am fairly new to IOS and Swift environment (I DON'T KNOW OBJ-C). I was trying to understand a concept but couldn't find any code example to
see this concept in working.Moreover I have no idea how to go about it.

- **As far as I know, View is a generic component.**
- **As View is a generic component it can be accessed by one of more ViewControllers.**
- **A View exposes its functionalities using protocols.**

**Example:**

**We have 2 ViewControllers:**

`ViewControllerOne`

`ViewControllerTwo`

**We have 1 View**

`ViewGeneric`

[image: Fig.1]

**Here, ViewGeneric is a generic component and exposes 3 of its functionalities,**

1. Change the background colour
2. Change label text
3. Change font colour of the text

Now I wish the `ViewControllerOne` to use the functionality to change colour of the View's background and

`ViewControllerTwo` to use the functionality to change label text and font colour of the text. Obviously one at a time.

**Its like I am reusing the ViewGeneric here.**

Please provide an small working example code in Swift.... I will be really grateful if one can help me understand how to go about it.

Comment: Don't know what you meant generic.  ViewGeneric is a class object.  You can create an instance of it to use in any other view controller.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you want, but this is a simple one like you have requested. First create your new custom UIView:

```
import UIKit

class MyGenericView: UIView {

    var myLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.myLabel = UILabel()

        // e.g.
        self.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 20)
        addSubview(myLabel)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Then you can use this view in different view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    var myGenericView: MyGenericView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myGenericView = MyGenericView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        myGenericView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        myGenericView.myLabel.text = "ViewController1 text"

        self.view.addSubview(myGenericView)
    }
}
```

The same view in another view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var myGenericView: MyGenericView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myGenericView = MyGenericView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
        myGenericView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        myGenericView.myLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        myGenericView.myLabel.text = "ViewController2 text"

        self.view.addSubview(myGenericView)
    }

}
```

Important in this case for understanding is the "addSubview" method which takes an UIView and add's it as an "subview" (or child-view) of the current view. This creates a view hierarchy with parent-child relationships, which means - if the parent moves then the child moves with the parent.